# New iPhone 11 crashes and reboots every day

Tags: iphone, crash

I have a new iPhone 11 with iOS 13.3. It crashes about twice a day. The log file always says:

```
{"bug_type":"210","timestamp":"2020-01-04 15:39:19.96 
+0100","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)","incident_id":"B567F658- 
1564-4CC2-B16E-5C9F0688A6FA"}
{
  "build" : "iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)",
  "product" : "iPhone12,1",
  "kernel" : "Darwin Kernel Version 19. 2.0: Mon Nov  4 17:46:45 PST 
  2019; root:xnu-6153.60.66~39\/RELEASE_ARM64_T8030",
  "incident" : "B567F658-1564-4CC2-B16E-5C9F0688A6FA",
  "crashReporterKey" : "b1ee133c43136a8fa3db5290258fc370a6cc6fe6",
  "date" : "2020-01-04 15:39:16.75 +0100",
  "panicString" : "panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff01129e068): AOP PANIC - No pulse on 0x116b1c0 - main(3)\nNo pulse on 0x116b1c0\nRTKit: RTKit_iOS-1264.60.6.0.1.release - Client: AppleSPUFirmwareBuilder-233.0.4~13261
...
```

It always fails with the error `AOP PANIC - No pulse on 0x116b1c0` (always this exact address). Any idea where this error could come from?

Comment: It might be bad memory.  I recommend taking it back to be replaced.

Comment: You have free apple support.  I'd give them a call.

Comment: I talked to apple support and they told me to send the phone in ... So, I hopefully this will be resolved. Thank you all.